# extracting ip address from a file

Tags: text-processing, awk, regular-expression

I'm trying to extract all the IP address from a file.

**FILE**

```
*>i85.95.2.160/29   172.16.24.4              0    200      0 64515 4445 15412 i
*>i85.112.80.0/28   172.16.24.4              0    200      0 6774 64521 i
*>i85.112.80.96/27  172.16.24.4              0    200      0 6774 64521 i
*>i85.115.64.96/27  172.16.24.4              0    200      0 2300 64961 i
```

**OUTPUT**

```
85.95.2.160
85.112.80.0
85.112.80.96
85.115.64.96
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$ awk < ips '{ print $1 }' grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' ips | sort | uniq
```

The problem is that from the list of IP addresses it goes from the beginning up to:

```
84.241.254.8/29
```

It does not extract any of the following ip addresses:

```
84.241.254.32
85.115.240.0
91.232.100.72
103.248.251.48
121.58.160.79
160.218.26.16
200.6.224.96
223.255.231.240
```

Any ideas why these aren't getting extracted?

Comment: Can you confirm what you posted, it's not working for me. I think you meant this: `awk < ips '{ print $1 }' | grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' | sort | uniq`?

Comment: Please also include sample lines with the IPs that are failing. I tried what you gave and it appears to work.

Comment: Yes, the lines that are failing are these:

     223.255.231.240

     217.175.164.56

     203.88.5.115

     84.241.254.32

     85.115.240.0

     91.232.100.72

     103.248.251.48
121.58.160.79
160.218.26.16
200.6.224.96
223.255.231.240

Thank you

Comment: Do update the question please - it's hard to tell what the lines should look like from the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a more accurate regex for matching an IPv4 address:

> (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)

It will place each octet into its own capture group. If you don't want that, then this following one captures the full address into a single capture group:

> ((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)

---

Having said that, I don't think the problem is your regex.

By the way, this should be a comment, not an answer... but it would be an extremely messy comment.

Comment: Thank you very much to every one. Thank you for your help. Probably I should add that I am using Cygwin. Thank you.